# Pandas add one day to column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to add 1 day to each date I want to get the begining date of the following month eg 2014-01-2014 for the 1st item in the dataframe.
I tried:

```
montdist['date'] + pd.DateOffset(1)
```

Which gives me:

```
TypeError: cannot use a non-absolute DateOffset in datetime/timedelta operations [<DateOffset>]
```

Have a Dataframe:

```
    Units   mondist                date
1    6491  0.057785 2013-12-31 00:00:00
2    7377  0.065672 2014-01-31 00:00:00
3    9990  0.088934 2014-02-28 00:00:00
4   10362  0.092245 2014-03-31 00:00:00
5   11271  0.100337 2014-04-30 00:00:00
6   11637  0.103596 2014-05-31 00:00:00
7   10199  0.090794 2014-06-30 00:00:00
8   10486  0.093349 2014-07-31 00:00:00
9    9282  0.082631 2014-08-31 00:00:00
10   8632  0.076844 2014-09-30 00:00:00
11   8204  0.073034 2013-10-31 00:00:00
12   8400  0.074779 2013-11-30 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Make it a DatetimeIndex first:

```
pd.DatetimeIndex(montdist['date']) + pd.DateOffset(1)
```

*Note: I think there is a feature request that this could work with date columns...*

In action:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(['21-11-2013', '22-11-2013'])

In [13]: pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date) + pd.DateOffset(1)
Out[13]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-11-22 00:00:00, 2013-11-23 00:00:00]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: None

In [14]: pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date) + pd.offsets.Hour(1)
Out[14]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-11-21 01:00:00, 2013-11-22 01:00:00]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: Non
```

Comment: @dartdog DatetimeIndex is has several date specific methods to play with, but a column doesn't (yet).

Comment: `pd.DateOffset(<number_of_days>)` also works in general, if you have a date in pandas and want to add/subtract some number of days.

Answer (score 65):

I think that the cleanest way to do this is a variant of szu's answer. Pandas has nearly full support datetime built into its functionality, so there is no need to load datetime; instead, if you are already using pandas, create the new column like this:

```
mondist['shifted_date'] = mondist.date + pd.Timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Nice.. Good improvement

Comment: I prefer this as it doesn't need any additional library :)

Answer (score 28):

Try to use timedelta():

```
mondist['shifted_date']=mondist.date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Nice.. although @Andy Hayden 's solution works fine for me in this case. It is good to know that you can directly manipulate dates in a non-indexed column..

Comment: This one is faster for me

Answer (score 7):

No need to turn into an index. Just using `.apply()` works:

```
df['newdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).apply(pd.DateOffset(1))
```

Comment: Seems that the feature has been added for columns vs indexes.., thanks for the update!

Answer (score 5):

One quick mention. if you are using data-frames and your datatype is `datetime64[ns]` non indexed, Then I would go as below:
Assuming the date column name is 'Date to Change by 1' and you want to change all dates by  1 day.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date, time

before
['Date to Change by 1'] = 1/31/2020

df['Date to Change by 1'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Date to Change by 1']) + 
timedelta(1)

After
['Date to Change by 1'] = 2/01/2020
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell `tshift` is a bit faster than doing math such as `+ pd.DateOffset` etc. Of course it only applies to Series or Dataframe indices, not columns.. but you could do:

```
df['newdate'] = pd.Series(index=df.index).tshift(periods=1, freq='D').index
```

If your df is large, this may shave off half the time - at least it did for me, which is why I'm using it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a string as an argument to [`Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html). For example:

```
pd.Timedelta('1 day') # pd.Timedelta('24 hours')
```

Output:

```
Timedelta('1 days 00:00:00')
```

To add a day to a column:

```
df['col'] + pd.Timedelta('1 day')
```

Other possible values:

- ‘W’ (week)
- ‘D’ / ‘days’ / ‘day’
- ‘hours’ / ‘hour’ / ‘hr’ / ‘h’
- ‘m’ / ‘minute’ / ‘min’ / ‘minutes’ / ‘T’
- ‘S’ / ‘seconds’ / ‘sec’ / ‘second’
- ‘ms’ / ‘milliseconds’ / ‘millisecond’ / ‘milli’ / ‘millis’ / ‘L’
- ‘us’ / ‘microseconds’ / ‘microsecond’ / ‘micro’ / ‘micros’ / ‘U’
- ‘ns’ / ‘nanoseconds’ / ‘nano’ / ‘nanos’ / ‘nanosecond’ / ‘N’