# Sum date with integer in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe, in which I want to create a new column which will sum two columns:

```
   index  Date          num  
0      0  2004-03-09      1  
1      1  2004-03-09      2
2      2  2004-03-09   -300
3      3  2004-03-09     -5
4      4  2004-03-09      3
```

Date is in date format and num is integer. The output should look like this:

```
    index Date          num  Date_2 
0      0  2004-03-09      1  2004-03-10
1      1  2004-03-09      2  2004-03-11
2      2  2004-03-09   -300  2003-05-14
3      3  2004-12-09     -5  2003-12-04
4      4  2004-02-09      3  2004-02-12
5      5  2004-05-09      3  2004-05-12
```

This was very straightforward to do in R, but since I have just started with Python I cannot figure it out. 
(Of course when I try to sum the columns I get an error that they are incompatible for operation)

```
[In]: df['Date_2'] = df['Date'] + df['num']

[Out]: incompatible type for a datetime/timedelta operation [__add__]
```

I tried converting the 'num' column in days, but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: show your code, please

Comment: df['Date_2'] = df['Date'] + df['num'] --> Of course, I get the error of incompatibility

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45602469/edit) and add it please.

Comment: Please read the following to improve your question: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can probably find a suitable solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20480897/pandas-add-one-day-to-column

Comment: @PauloAlmeida That answer is outdated. Pandas now has a Timedelta scalar object: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/timedeltas.html

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Thanks, I've checked that solution before posting, however my offset/delta is not fixed.

Comment: @Katerina Oh right, I didn't even notice that was just for one day. Anyway, it's solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`incompatible type ... [__add__]` means that the two objects you are trying to add do not implement the `__add__` magic method in such a way that they handle each others object types.

You need a timedelta-related object that can be created from ints from your integer column that is compatible with the dates in your dataframe.

Assuming you are using Pandas dataframes, Pandas has a Timedelta scalar type that you can create from an `int` like so: `Timedelta(df['num'], unit='d')`

Answer (score 2):

```
In [277]: df['Date2'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Date + np.timedelta64(x.num, 'D'), 
     ...: axis=1)

In [278]: df
Out[278]: 
   index       Date  num      Date2
0      0 2004-03-09    1 2004-03-10
1      1 2004-03-09    2 2004-03-11
2      2 2004-03-09 -300 2003-05-14
3      3 2004-03-09   -5 2004-03-04
4      4 2004-03-09    3 2004-03-12
```

Comment: should be +, not -

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I did that.

Comment: Thanks, this also works. The accepted solution is much faster in large datasets though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use datetime.timedelta(days=`num`).
Like below:

```
df['Date_2'] = df['Date'] + datetime.timedelta(days=df['num'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach using `pd.to_datetime` and `pd.to_timedelta`.

`df['date2']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])+pd.to_timedelta(df['num'].astype(np.int),'D')`

May this one help you.